# jQuery/Javascript add/remove this.class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
$(".image-popup").on('click', function() {
       $(this).find(".myModal").addClass("modal-active");
       $(".modal-active").css("display", "block");
   });
$(".close").on('click', function() {
       $(".modal-active").css("display", "none");
       var myVar = $(this).closest(".image-popup");
       myVar.find(".myModal").removeClass("modal-active");
       $(".modal-active").css("display","none");
   });
</script>
```

I am attempting to have a modal appear and then disappear when I click the close button. The problem is that the removeClass() will not work and the "display", "none" will not override the first click function. Any Help?

Comment: Is `.close` inside `.image-popup`? if so, add `evt` as a parameter in the close click callback function and then add `evt.preventDefault();` to stop the event from bubbling up the DOM.

Comment: .close is inside of .image-popup

Answer (score 0):

My guess from your question and your comment above is that the event from your second handler is bubbling up to your first handler:

```
$(".image-popup").on('click', function() {
    $(this).find(".myModal")
        .addClass("modal-active")
        .show();
});

$(".close").on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    $(this).closest(".image-popup")
        .find(".myModal")
        .removeClass("modal-active");
        .hide();
});
```

Try to prevent the event from bubbling out of the `.close` handler by using `evt.preventDefault();`

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. When I inspect the element and I click on the close button it acts like it is taking the code but it will not properly execute.

Comment: @sethrandall Can you describe what you mean by _"...will not properly execute."_? Is it throwing an error in the console?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with this simple solution:

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-popup">
<div class="show-modal btn btn-success">Show Modal</div>
  <div class="myModal">
  <div class="close btn btn-success">Close</div>
  <p>My Modal is active</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal-active .myModal{
  display: block;
}
.myModal{
  display:none;
}
.close{
  color:red;
  display:block;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('.show-modal').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('modal-active');
  });
  $('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.image-popup').removeClass('modal-active');
  });
});
```

See this fiddle for more details https://jsfiddle.net/a3yze54w/1/